# Terraform file for gcp, how to input path for json key

Tags: google-cloud-platform, configuration, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I am studying trying to learning how to deploy using Terraform in gcp.
Would anyone know how to write the **path** for the json key in the configuration file mentioned in the template bellow.

I am getting an error in line 11

```
 credentials = file("C:\\Users\Administrator\\Desktop\\Terraform\\mykey.json")
```

output:

```
│ Error: Invalid escape sequence
│
│   on main.tf line 11, in provider "google":
│   11:   credentials = file("C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Terraform\mykey.json")
│
│ The symbol "l" is not a valid escape sequence selector.
```

template example:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    google = {
      source = "hashicorp/google"
      version = "3.5.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "google" {
  credentials = file("<NAME>.json")

  project = "<PROJECT_ID>"
  region  = "us-central1"
  zone    = "us-central1-c"
}

resource "google_compute_network" "vpc_network" {
  name = "terraform-network"
}
```

Comment: You have modified the question changing the problem after you received an answer for your first problem. Do not do that - create a new question. Restore the original problem and post a new question with the new problem.

Comment: well, this is the same problem. how to write the credential path at terraform config file. The way I wrote the path to begin, is only a starting point but it could be completed wrong. Thats why Im asking for help

Comment: Post a question - receive an answer. Then post a new question with the next problem. Do not use Stack Overflow to create debugging sessions. Otherwise, the answers you receive will not make sense to future readers as you are modifying the question after receiving an answer.

Comment: it makes sense, I totally see your point, apologizes. Let me try deleting the question.

Comment: Don't delete the question, roll it back to your original question.

Comment: Done, I've reverted the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The character **\** is often an [escape](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequences_in_C#Table_of_escape_sequences) character and is combined with the next character.

Specify the credentials file:

```
credentials = file("C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\Terraform\\mykey.json")
```

or like this - file() is not necessary:

```
credentials = "C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\Terraform\\mykey.json"
```

or use Unix path syntax:

```
credentials = "C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/Terraform/mykey.json"
```

Comment: Hi John I have updated the question with the error